# Can I install gems with apt-get on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubygems

I am new to Ruby and just diving in. The Ruby tutorial says I should get the packaging system from here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126

I am on Ubuntu Linux. The page has a .tar and a .gem option for downloading. Which should I download?

Also, are gems exactly analogous to Java jars? And why do I need the gem packaging system if I can just download gems one by one as they are needed?

Comment: I'll highly recommend using [RVM](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) to create a developer's sandbox on your host, unless you intend to use it as a production server. RVM is rapidly becoming the method of choice for installing Ruby and managing gems on MacOS and Linux systems. It's an easy install, just read through the directions first and follow them. Once RVM is installed on your machine type `rvm notes` and follow those directions. At that point you should be ready to let it install Ruby using `rvm install 1.9.2` followed by `gem install gemname`, for whatever gems you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, download *.tar file, unpack this file, then go to rubygems directory in your console, and type

```
ruby setup.rb
```

That's it :)

Comment: btw, into what directory is it best practice to unpack the tar file?  Thanks! :)

Comment: It doesn't matter, after installation you can remove rubygems directory.

Comment: It gives following error: `loading the /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb file caused an error.`

Answer (score 78):

On **Ubuntu 16.04** and **Ubuntu 18.04**, both `sudo apt-get install rubygems` and `sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration` failed for me. Instead, I had to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

Comment: You can use `apt-cache search ruby*` on ubuntu to check what are available fyi, i had to install `ruby3.1`.

Answer (score 74):

Ubuntu now have rubygems as a package

For Ubuntu 12:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
```

For Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration
```

Answer (score 12):

If on Ubuntu 14.04 try below

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration
```

Comment: Nice update, although the question is old and its reference to rubyforge.org doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

If you install the full ruby application set with

`sudo apt-get install ruby-full`

You will get gems and much more by default. Tested on Ubuntu 16, it could also work on other version.

Answer (score 4):

For me in **Ubuntu 20.04** I did 3 things to create a new Ruby and Rails app.

1. Install Ruby development version

```
sudo apt install ruby-dev
```

2. Install rails from gem

```
sudo gem install rails
```

3. Create new application

```
rails new blog
```

I got error while installing rails(`sudo apt install rails`) only, So I installed devlopment version. I got permission related error while not using **Sudo** as well while installing gems and rails.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu

First install ruby:

```
sudo apt install ruby
```

Note that : `sudo snap install ruby` will throw this error :

> error: This revision of snap "ruby" was published using classic
>   confinement and
>          thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security
>          sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system at
>          risk.
>
> ```
>    If you understand and want to proceed repeat the command including
>    --classic.
> ```

Finally, download latest tar version of ruby gems here:
https://rubygems.org/pages/download

Unzip and cd to the folder and finally type in terminal:

```
sudo ruby setup.rb
```