# Error when creating a Docker image for Ruby On Rails environment (from a Dockerfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I guess it's a environment problem.
When I do it manually (without a Dockerfile) it works.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade --assume-yes
RUN apt-get install wget vim git --assume-yes
# install RVM
RUN apt-get install build-essential curl --assume-yes
RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN echo 'source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c "rvm requirements"
# install Ruby
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c "rvm autolibs enable"
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c "rvm install 2.1.2"
# install Rails
RUN echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc
RUN gem install rails -v 4.1.5
# install nodeJS
RUN sudo apt-get install nodejs --assume-yes
EXPOSE 3000
```

Than I build with:

```
sudo docker build -t="james/rails" .
```

I get that error:

```
Step 11 : RUN gem install rails -v 4.1.5
 ---> Running in 44efc6b7c254
/bin/sh: 1: gem: not found
2014/09/04 18:33:52 The command [/bin/sh -c gem install rails -v 4.1.5] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Using rvm without a shell is tricky. Also the point of rvm is to manage multiple installations of ruby, and with docker you do not need that. Just go with some working ruby base image, for example binaryphile/ruby (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/binaryphile/ruby/), or you can use my rbenv based image: cthulhu666/docker-rbenv (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/cthulhu666/docker-rbenv/) if you don't like installing things as root (and I encourage you to not install things as root). As a sidenote, doing 'apt-get upgrade' in Dockerfile is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install rails -v 4.1.5"` instead of the line you've got in there. Does that change anything?

Comment: What happens when you use `/bin/bash -l -c` or a similar `/bin/sh` command for all the RVM install lines?

Comment: @AlexLynham `gem` is actually a rvm wrapper. The interactive and login bash shell will load/set up some environment variables for rvm. `-lc` makes sure rvm set up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

With the help from Alex Lynham, here's a working Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget vim git --assume-yes

# install RVM
RUN apt-get install build-essential curl --assume-yes
RUN curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN echo 'source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
RUN /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell -c "rvm requirements"

# install Ruby
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm autolibs enable"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.1.2"

# install Rails
RUN echo "gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri" >> ~/.gemrc
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "gem install rails -v 4.1.5"

# install nodeJS
RUN sudo apt-get install nodejs --assume-yes

EXPOSE 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install rubygems before being able to use it.

```
RUN apt-get install rubygems
```

see also : [Can I install gems with apt-get on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736568/can-i-install-gems-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu)

Comment: RVM takes care of that.

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea to install RubyGems from aptitude, you're asking for trouble :)