# linux source command not working when building Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that defines a Ruby on Rails stack.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER example <examplen@example.com>

# Update
RUN apt-get update

# Install Ruby and Rails dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y \
ruby \
ruby-dev \
build-essential \
libxml2-dev \
libxslt1-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libsqlite3-dev \
nodejs \
curl

RUN gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3

RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails

RUN /bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Install Rails
RUN gem install rails

# Create a new Rails app under /src/my-app
RUN mkdir -p /src/new-app

RUN rails new /src/new-app

WORKDIR /src/my-app

# Default command is to run a rails server on port 3000
CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding", "0.0.0.0", "--port" ,"3000"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

When I execute the command `docker build -t anotherapp/my-rails-app .` I get the following error:

> Removing intermediate container 3f8060cdc6f5
>   Step 8 : RUN gem install rails
>    ---> Running in 8c1793414e63
>   ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>           activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
>   The command '/bin/sh -c gem install rails' returned a non-zero code: 1

It looks like the command `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` isn't working during the build.

I'm not sure exactly why this is happening.

Comment: The command is working, but when the command finishes, the shell exits and everything is gone again.

Comment: you should maybe not use rvm to install rails, but if you want to you should chain all the `RUN`s since each of them create a new layer and are probably not aware of your bash sourcing

Comment: Have you read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25685004/1981061 ?

Answer (score 12):

From the [docker builder reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder), each RUN command is run independently. So doing `RUN source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` does not have any effect on the next RUN command.

Try changing the operations which require the given source file as follows

```
  RUN /bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ; gem install rails"
```

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it's another way to approach the problem.

Docker provides an [official](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/) [Ruby image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/). This is the image the [Docker Compose and Rails](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) quickstart tutorial uses. As you can see from their example (below), you can copy your Gemfile.lock into your image and run `bundle install` without having to worry about RVM.

```
FROM ruby:2.2.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

You will normally only have one rails application running inside a container using a specific version of Ruby so RVM's ability to manage multiple version of Ruby won't be helpful.

If you are curious how the official images are made, the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/e89be7d60685ec51a193a358a8f3364b287aee3b/2.3/Dockerfile) is on Github.

---

As to why this is happening. As others pointed out, [`source`](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do) command executes the file in the current shell. Each [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/run) instruction

> ... will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results. The resulting committed image will be used for the next step in the Dockerfile.

Each `RUN`, `ADD`, `COPY` instruction essentially starts a new shell in a new container and executes a command.

```
1 RUN /bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
2 RUN gem install rails
```

Can be read as

```
1 Start a brand new shell
  Execute: source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm
  Save the state of the file system as an image
  Exit shell

2 Start a brand new shell
  Execute: gem install rails
  ...
```

When step 1 finishes, the shell (and everything your sourced into it), goes away.