# docker run script which exports env variables

Tags: shell, docker, dockerfile

I've search some of the questions already like [docker ENV vs RUN export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export), which explains differences between those commands, but didn't help in solving my problem.

For example I have a script called `myscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PLATFORM_HOME="$(pwd)"
```

And have following lines in Dockerfile:

```
...
COPY myscript.sh /
RUN ./myscript.sh
```

I've also tried to use ENTRYPOINT instead of RUN or declaring variable before calling the script, all that with no success.

What I want to achieve is that `PLATFORM_HOME` can be referenced from other Dockerfiles which use that one as a base. How to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to export a variable from a script to a child image. As a general rule, environment variables travel down, never up to a parent.

[`ENV`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) will persist in the build environment and to child images and containers.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM busybox
ENV PLATFORM_HOME test
RUN echo $PLATFORM_HOME
```

`Dockerfile.child`

```
FROM me/platform
RUN echo $PLATFORM_HOME
CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo $PLATFORM_HOME"]
```

Build the parent

```
docker build -t me/platform .
```

Then build the child:

```
→ docker build -f Dockerfile.child -t me/platform-test  .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM me/platform
 ---> 539b52190af4
Step 2/3 : RUN echo $PLATFORM_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 40e0bfa872ed
Step 3/3 : CMD sh -c echo $PLATFORM_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c0e842f99fd
Successfully built 0c0e842f99fd
Successfully tagged me/platform-test:latest
```

Then run

```
→ docker run --rm me/platform-test
test
```

Comment: +1 To phrase it slightly differently, `RUN` in a Dockerfile executes the command, and upon the exit of that command, the filesystem changes are persisted in a layer of the image being created. Changes to the environment, spawned daemon processes, etc, are not captured in the image.

Answer (score 3):

I think export sets the environment variables for the child processes. So it really doesn't matter if you do RUN or ENTRYPOINT. In reading [linux source command not working when building Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044810/linux-source-command-not-working-when-building-dockerfile), I feel source command cannot help either.

You need to use ENV if you want to set the environment variables in Dockerfile.

Comment: so this is not possible now as I understand, right ?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `ENV PLATFORM_HOME=$(pwd)` in your Dockerfile. Variable will be accessible in every container you will create from the Dockerfile.

Comment: well, the question is about exporting it from script. i can't using it as ENV, because this script is not mine