# /bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, stream-framework

i'm trying to build a docker file with docker-compose up but i get error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c poetry install && bundler install' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

here it is my docker file and docker-compose-yml file:
dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python

WORKDIR /stream

ADD . /stream

CMD ["cat", "/etc/os-release"]


RUN poetry install && \
bundler install


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - REDISTOGO_URL=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Answer (score 4):

add this to your Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7

ENV LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib

RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python

WORKDIR /stream

ADD . /stream

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin"

RUN poetry install && \
bundler install


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/root/.poetry/bin/poetry", "run", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

on the other hand you need to setup a `network` in `compose` to be able to connect between the services using the service name.

Comment: I tested it , it works. you need to delete your old images and build it again. it would also helpful if you say what does not worked

Comment: i did it and i got this error:
/root/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py2.7/subprocess32.py:149: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
                                           
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c poetry install && bundler install' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: try to add `pip install -U subprocess32` before `RUN poetry install`

Answer (score 2):

The `poetry` binary is not found because its location is not yet in the `PATH` environment variable. The `poetry` installer only adds a command in your `.profile` but it does not re-load those settings. In the `Dockerfile` after the `poetry` installalation command you need to add this line (it re-loads `.profile`)

```
RUN source ${HOME}/.profile
```

The `poetry` installer writes to `${HOME}/.profile`

This has the benefit of not specifying that in this case `$HOME` is `/root` (in case you need to later a user, and not execute your server as root for security reasons)

Comment: This doesn't work. Each docker instruction starts a new shell in a new container. Whatever you sourced won't be carried over to the next step. [For more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044810/linux-source-command-not-working-when-building-dockerfile)

Comment: I tried this. Now it says 
 > RUN source ${HOME}/.profile:
   11 0.150 /bin/sh: 1: source: not found

Answer (score 0):

AS per official documentation you need to set the env variable for poetry, there is also a new installation function/link but the new installer if for python 3 syntax

try

```
FROM python:[3x]

# ENV for poetry https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#using-environment-variables
# make poetry create the virtual environment in the project's root, it gets named `.venv`
# and do not ask any interactive question
ENV POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1

# Prepend poetry and venv to path
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y curl \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python

# Update poetry to latest version
RUN poetry self update

WORKDIR /stream
ADD . /stream

CMD ["cat", "/etc/os-release"]

RUN poetry install && \
bundler install


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Dockerfile

```
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"
```